# how to give pagination in specific pages of wordpress?

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

My site name or wordpress folder name is gift. I need to give pagination in

H:\xampp\htdocs\gift\wp-content\plugins\node\display.php .

display.php consist of following code

```
<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>age</td></tr>
      <?php 
         $sql=mysql_query("select * from record"); 
         while(  $adf=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
        ?>
          <tr><td><?php echo $adf['name'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $adf['name'];?></td></tr>
             <?php } ?></table>
```

the result is

```
            Name  age
            shon   12
            peter  13
                etc.....
```

Now i need to give pagination in this page

.Because there were more than 100 data s are fetched.i need to display only 5 record at a time .

If anyone know then help me.Remember it is not a ordinary php page .It is a word press work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this trick : http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/06/22/how-to-add-pagination-into-list-of-records-or-wordpress-plugin/

But to me, given you just have a hundred items, the simplest way is to pass by a JQuery plugin, like [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) or [Dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com/). These plugins allow easily to add pagination, but also sorting and filtering features.

An example of custom pagination : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html